# Ninject and repository pattern with interfaces

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, ninject, ninject-2

This is the interfaces/class structure I have now:

BaseContentObject abstract class

```
public abstract class BaseContentObject : IEquatable<BaseContentObject>
{
...
}
```

Page concrete class

```
public class Page : BaseContentObject
{
...
}
```

Repository interface

```
public interface IContentRepository<T>
    {
        // common methods for all content types
        void Insert(T o);
        void Update(T o);
        void Delete(string slug);
        void Delete(ContentType contentType, string slug);
        IEnumerable<T> GetInstances();
        T GetInstance(ContentType contentType, string slug);
        T GetInstance(string contentType, string slug);
        T GetInstance(string slug);
        IEnumerable<string> GetSlugsForContentType(int limit = 0, string query = "");
        ContentList GetContentItems();
        bool IsUniqueSlug(string slug);
        string ObjectPersistanceFolder { get; set; }
    }
```

Common interface implementation (for all content classes that inherit BaseContentObject class)

```
    public class XmlRepository<T> : IContentRepository<BaseContentObject>
    {
        public string ObjectPersistanceFolder { get; set; }

        public XmlRepository()
        {
            ObjectPersistanceFolder = Path.Combine(XmlProvider.DataStorePhysicalPath, typeof(T).Name);
            if (!Directory.Exists(ObjectPersistanceFolder))
                Directory.CreateDirectory(ObjectPersistanceFolder);
        }
...
}
```

Content specific repository

```
public class XmlPagesRepository : XmlRepository<Page> { }
```

Ninject rule in global.asax.cs

```
Bind<IContentRepository<Page>>().To<XmlPagesRepository>();
```

that gives the following compile time error:

```
*The type 'Namespace.XmlPagesRepository' cannot be used as type parameter 'TImplementation' in the generic type or method 'Ninject.Syntax.IBindingToSyntax<T>.To<TImplementation>()'. There is no implicit reference conversion from 'Namespace.XmlPagesRepository' to 'Namespace.IContentRepository<Namespace.Page>'.*
```

I've spent quite some time figuring out my classes and interfaces structure to support my business needs. Now I don't know how to get past that Ninject error.

I want to use this structure in ASP.NET MVC controllers like this:

```
    public IContentRepository<Page> ContentRepository { get; private set; }

    public PageController(IContentRepository<Page> repository)
    {
        ContentRepository = repository;
    }
```

Comment: Wouldnt hurt to give the compile time error - it'll open this up to people who have hit this issue and solved it without even considering it as being a big issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think if you create a test case using the concrete classes you'll find that indeed you can't implicitly convert from `XmlPagesRepository` to `IContentRepository<Page>`. It's hard to follow, but if that conversion is possible then I think bind it using `ToMethod`:

```
Bind<IContentRepository<Page>>().ToMethod(x => (IContentRepository<Page>)kernel.Get<XmlPagesRepository>());
```

Edit: In looking at this some more, the conversion isn't possible. `XmlRepository<Page>` implements`IContentRepository<BaseContentObject>` not `IContentRepository<Page>`. It doesn't matter that Page is a BaseContentObject, the cast isn't possible. This isn't going to work as you intended.

Edit2: "Implement" refers to implementing an interface; you implement an interface and inherit from (or extend) a class. Without fully understanding what you're trying to do, this is how I would design the repositories:

```
public interface IPageRepository : IContentRepository<Page>
{
}

public interface XmlPageRepository : IPageRepository
{
    // implementation
}
```

You can now have multiple implementations of IPageRepository and bind the appropriate one using Ninject:

```
Bind<IPageRepository>().To<XmlPageRepository>();
```

Comment: If you can understand what my case (semantically) requires, can you suggest a alternative implementation?

Comment: If you want to continue down the same path you can just create a an `IContentRepository<Page>` implementation. I suggest defining `IPageRepository` (perhaps implementing `IContentRepository<Page>`) implemented by a `XmlPageRepository` implementing it.

Comment: I'm having hard time understanding what you mean exactly because you use words implemented and implementing a couple of times. If you can clarify it or better yet modify my code in your answer to the level that I can visualize what you mean, I will accept your answer.